# laravel 5 ajax error request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hi I was wondering why my Laravel 5 Ajax request doesnt work

```js
        <input type="hidden" class="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}" name="_token">

 $.ajax({
          url: "{{ route('groups.store') }}",
          method: 'post',
          data: {
            name: 'name',
            _token: $("input[name=_token]").val()
          },
          success: function(response) {
            if (response.success == true) {
              // remove error message
              alert('success');
            }
          },
          error: function(xhr) {
              alert('error');
            }
          });
```

on the Route File I put:

```
    Route::post('search/store', [
        'uses' => 'SearchController@store',
        'as' => 'groups.store'
    ]);
```

and on my controller I put:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }
```

then I keep getting error 404  while I simply wants to display the json result from my controller much help appreciated thx

btw heres the full routes.php

```
    <?php
carbon()->setLocale('id');


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
    Route::post('search/SearchController','SearchController@postMapSearchResult');
    Route::get('/getRequest', function(){
            if(Request::ajax()){
                return 'getRequest has loaded';
            }
        });


Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    // Backend Area
        Route::controller('login','Backend\LoginController');

        Route::get('admin-cp' , function(){
            return redirect('login');
        });

        if(request()->segment(1) == webarq()->backendUrl)
        {
            include __DIR__.'/backendRoutes.php';
        }
    //

    // Frontend Area

        Route::get('account/confirmation/{token}', 'Auth\AuthController@activateUser')->name('user.activate');
        Route::controller('faq','FaqController');
        Route::controller('blog','BlogController');
        Route::controller('social','SocialController');
        Route::controller('account','AccountController');
        Route::controller('iklan','IklanController');
        Route::controller('search','SearchController');
        Route::controller('/','HomeController');


        Route::post('search/store', [
            'uses' => 'SearchController@store',
            'as' => 'groups.store'
        ]);


});
```

Comment: Can you post your full routes by php artisan route list it seems it matches to another route

Comment: there i added my routes.php file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put the route outside of middleware group

Comment: I tried localhost/projectname/public/search/store , and it returns 'error' alert

Comment: @Hendry open your browser's dev tools and see what error is that.

Comment: jquery-latest.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/projectname/public/search/store 404 (Not Found)

Comment: added http://localhost/projectname/public/search/store still no luck :( @PanagiotisKoursaris

Comment: Do you really need the name of route 'groups.store' ?

Comment: nope @PanagiotisKoursaris anything works for me as long as i can pass param and return json result with ajax in laravel 5

Comment: Then change the route, Look at my updated answer and try again

Comment: @PanagiotisKoursaris  same error 404 

jquery-latest.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/projectname/public/search/store 404

Comment: Put the route outside of middleware group

Comment: @PanagiotisKoursaris just did and same error appear 404

Comment: @PanagiotisKoursaris hei wait it works when I put it above the middle ware route, but still 404 when I put the route at the verry bottom while outside the group thx so much! :D

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a code which work perfect for me.

```
var count = 100;
    $('#ID').on("click", ".CLASS",function() {

                var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'URL',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN,id:count},
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('success');
                        console.log(data);

                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);


                    }
                });

            });
```

Comment: He has  `csrf_token` passed in his `$.ajax`. If you look closely.

Comment: Thanks Ivanka Todorova, Your are right. But this code work for me.

Comment: I tried yours @IvankaTodorova and i still get error 404, btw it also says count is not defined, where do you define that btw? and what for?

Comment: Count is the variable i am just using to pass data. You can specify any value to count and In URL please specify full path from localhost and then try it.

Comment: @LavanyaPant yeah still no luck tho